# Diff of two strings in Scala

Tags: string, scala, collections, diff

Suppose I am writing `diff(s1: String, s2: String): List[String]` to check if `s1` == `s2` and return a list of errors :

- `s1[i] != s2[i]` the error is `s1[i] != s2[i]`
- `s1[i]` if `i >= s2.length` the error is `s1[i] is undefined`
- `s2[i]` if `i >= s1.length` the error is `s2[i] is missing`

for example:

```
diff("a", "a")     // returns Nil
diff("abc", "abc") // Nil
diff("xyz", "abc") // List("x != a", "y != b", "z != c")
diff("abcd", "ab") // List("c is undefined", "d is undefined")
diff("ab", "abcd") // List("c is missing", "d is missing")
diff("", "ab")     // List("a is missing", "b is missing")  
diff("axy", "ab")  // List("x != b", "y is undefined")
```

How would you write it ?

P.S. I am writing `diff` like that:

```
def compare(pair: (Option[Char], Option[Char])) = pair match { 
  case (Some(x), None)    => Some(s"$x is undefined")
  case (None, Some(y))    => Some(s"$y is missing")
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => if (x != y) Some(s"$x != $y") else None 
  case _ => None
}

def diff(s1: String, s2: String) = {
  val os1 = s1.map(Option.apply)
  val os2 = s2.map(Option.apply)
  os1.zipAll(os2, None, None).flatMap(compare)
}
```

Comment: Are you prioritizing clarity and correctness? If so your implementation looks pretty good to me. If you will be applying it to very large strings or you care about performance, though, it's not at all what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! I am prioritizing clarity but now I am slowly realizing that traversing the strings _three_ times is clearly suboptimal. I will think how to improve it.

Comment: If you're looking for general improvements to your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better site.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will post this question there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A little more concise

First of all, here's how I'd implement this method off the top of my head:

```
def diff(s1: String, s2: String): List[String] =
  (s1, s2).zipped.collect {
    case (x, y) if x != y => s"$x != $y"
  }.toList ++
    s1.drop(s2.length).map(x => s"$x is undefined") ++
    s2.drop(s1.length).map(y => s"$y is missing")
```

It's about half as many characters as your original implementation, and to my eye it's at least as readable. You could argue that the `drop` trick is a little too clever, and you'd probably be right, but I think it reads nicely once you get it.

### A little more efficient

A method like this is self-contained and easy to test, and if there's any chance it's likely to be used in situations where performance is important, an imperative implementation is worth considering. Here's a quick sketch of how I'd do it:

```
def diffFast(s1: String, s2: String): IndexedSeq[String] = {
  val builder = Vector.newBuilder[String]

  def diff(short: String, long: String, status: String) = {
    builder.sizeHint(long.length)
    var i = 0

    while (i < short.length) {
      val x = s1.charAt(i)
      val y = s2.charAt(i)
      if (x != y) builder += s"$x != $y"
      i += 1
    }

    while (i < long.length) {
      val x = long.charAt(i)
      builder += s"$x is $status"
      i += 1
    }
  }

  if (s1.length <= s2.length) diff(s1, s2, "missing")
    else diff(s2, s1, "undefined")

  builder.result
}
```

You might be able to make this a *little* faster by hinting the size, etc. [update: I went ahead and added this], but this version is probably pretty close to optimal, and I also find it quite readable—it's not as clear to my eye as either my short implementation above or your original, but I find it much nicer than the recursive implementation in the other answer.

Note that this returns an `IndexedSeq`, not a `List`. In this it follows your original implementation, not the signature in your first sentence. If you need a `List` you can just change `Vector.newBuilder` to `List.newBuilder`, but the vector version is likely to be a little faster for most cases.

### Benchmarks

We could speculate about performance all day, but it's so easy to run some quick JMH microbenchmarks that we might as well do that instead (full source [here](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/d5a288ad677a57f47822a78e44747165)). I'll take the following pair of strings as a simple example:

```
val example1: String = "a" * 1000
val example2: String = "ab" * 100
```

We can measure throughput for this input for your original version (both as it is and returning a `List`), my concise version, my fast version (returning both `IndexedSeq` and `List`), and Tim's recursive version:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt       Score     Error  Units
DiffBench.checkConcise   thrpt   20   47412.127 ± 550.693  ops/s
DiffBench.checkFast      thrpt   20  108661.093 ± 371.827  ops/s
DiffBench.checkFastList  thrpt   20   91745.269 ± 157.128  ops/s
DiffBench.checkOrig      thrpt   20    8129.848 ±  59.989  ops/s
DiffBench.checkOrigList  thrpt   20    7916.637 ±  15.736  ops/s
DiffBench.checkRec       thrpt   20   62409.682 ± 580.529  ops/s
```

So in short: your original implementation is really pretty poor as far as performance is concerned (I'd guess more because of all the allocations than the multiple traversals), my concise implementation is competitive with the (arguably less readable) recursive one and gets about six times more throughput than the original, and the imperative implementation is close to twice as fast as any of the others.

Comment: Your implementation is not exactly the same as the original one (there is a difference between "is undefined" and "is missing" when the character is missing in the left/right string). It does not diminish the relevance of the optimized version :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Travis ! I liked both the concise implementation and benchmarks. Just did not find how you handle the "missing" case.

Comment: @Michael If you want to handle the missing characters asymmetrically, then `map` the two lists with the dropped prefix separately: `def diff(s1: String, s2: String): List[String] =
  (s1, s2).zipped.collect {
    case (x, y) if x != y => s"$x != $y"
  }.toList ++
  s1.drop(s2.length).map(_ + " is undefined") ++
  s2.drop(s1.length).map(_ + " is missing")`. In the optimized imperative version, you could pass the error message as third argument to `diff` in the `if-else`, this shouldn't change the results of the benchmarks significantly.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Got it :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for noting the problem with the message—I've updated the answer and am rerunning the benchmarks now.

Answer (score 1):

[ See below for original answer ]

This can be done with a recursive algorithm:

```
def diff(a: String, b: String): List[String] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[Char], r: List[Char], res: List[String]): List[String] =
    (l, r) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) =>
        res.reverse
      case (undef, Nil) =>
        res.reverse ++ undef.map(c => s"$c is undefined")
      case (Nil, miss) =>
        res.reverse ++ miss.map(c => s"$c is missing")
      case (lh :: lt, rh :: rt) if lh != rh =>
        loop(lt, rt, s"$lh != $rh" +: res)
      case (_ :: lt, _ :: rt) =>
        loop(lt, rt, res)
    }

  loop(a.toList, b.toList, Nil)
}
```

Personally I find this more obvious than using `Option`/`zipAll`/`flatMap`, but this is clearly a matter of taste and what you happen to be familiar with. I think this is more flexible because, for example, it can be easily modified to generate a single error string for all the undefined/missing characters.

If efficiency is important then this version uses `Iterator` to avoid creating temporary lists, and uses nested `if`/`else` rather than `match`:

```
def diff(a: String, b: String): List[String] = {
  val l = a.toIterator
  val r = b.toIterator

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(res: List[String]): List[String] =
    if (l.isEmpty) {
      res.reverse ++ r.map(c => s"$c is missing")
    } else {
      if (r.isEmpty) {
        res.reverse ++ l.map(c => s"$c is undefined")
      } else {
        val lhead = l.next()
        val rhead = r.next()

        if (lhead == rhead) {
          loop(res)
        } else {
          loop(s"$lhead != $rhead" +: res)
        }
      }
    }

  loop(Nil)
}
```

Thanks to Brian McCutchon for pointing out the problem with using `String` rather than `List[Char]`, and Andrey Tyukin for encouraging me to post a more efficient solution.

#### Original answer

A recursive implementation isn't too scary:

```
def diff(a: String, b: String): List[String] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: String, r: String, res: List[String]) : List[String] = (l, r) match {
    case ("", "") =>
      res
    case (lrem, "") =>
      res ++ lrem.map(c => s"$c is undefined")
    case ("", rrem) =>
      res ++ rrem.map(c => s"$c is missing")
    case _ if l.head != r.head =>
      loop(l.tail, r.tail, res :+ s"${l.head} != ${r.head}")
    case _ =>
      loop(l.tail, r.tail, res)
  }

 loop(a, b, Nil)
}
```

This should perform OK unless there are a lot of errors in which case appending to `res` will get expensive. You can fix this by prepending to `res` and then reversing at the end if necessary, but it makes the code less clear.

Comment: Who cares about "less clear" if this thing has the wrong asymptotic behavior? If you feed a medium sized source code file to it (50000 characters, between 1000 and 1500 lines, say), it unexpectedly hangs for over a minute. I assume that if you give it a short story with around 150000 characters,  it will never return. Even worse: it might "look OK" during tests, but then simply die in production, because no one would expect a O(n^2) algorithm for an obviously O(n) problem.

Comment: Your code is `O(n^2)` even if you fix the problem of appending to `List` and even if there are no errors, since you are repeatedly calling `tail` on strings. You could solve this by converting the strings to lists first. Overall, though, this solution is both less clear (IMO) and less efficient than the OP's code.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Thanks for your comments, I was thinking of lists and had missed the point about the cost of `tail` on a `String`. As to which is clearer I guess it is just a matter of opinion :). Since the output is clearly human-readable I was under the impression that this was not going to be used to generate large numbers of errors, and therefore the cost of the append would not be important.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I wrote the full version using `reverse` and it is more than just eight extra characters, so I opted for the simpler but less efficient version as a way of presenting a different approach to the problem.

Comment: @Tim, thank you for the detailed and thoughtful answer.